# Azure Search Filter search.ismatch function doesnt work with mixture of special characters like hiphen and single quote

Tags: azure, search, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have a following code,

```
filter="search.ismatch('Paris\-l''Hopital*', 'DestinationAddress/City', 'full', 'all')"
```

This filter should give me the record that has City with the name Paris-l'Hopital. Please note i am escaping the single quote in the middle of the search term with another single quote. Hiphen is escaped using backslash. Moreover the city field uses Microsoft Analyzer.

While i can see the record exists in the search index i cannot understand why this filter doesnt return the record i am expecting. Any input will be highly appreciated.

References
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By default it considers hyphen as a stopword. You need to change the default analyzer to not break into different words when it finds the '-'.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Not sure if we really need to change that. for e.g. if we are searching for something like "stockton-on-tees". It works fine. I have a feeling if we have a search term with dash and singlequote then it breaks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would suggest considering [a language-specific analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers) if you have content in a specific language. For addresses, this is tricky since you probably have to support all types of addresses. Have you tried using one of the French analyzers? It would probably do better at tokenizing typical French content.

Comment: Thank you Dan, This field not only stores French cities but cities from all over the world. Therefore i cannot rely only on French Analyzers.